# Do you have to honor parents’ demand for Chumra

Tags: halacha, family-members, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, yoreh-deah, stringency-chumrah

According to Halacha, do you have to honor your parents’ demand for you to observe Chumrahs? In the rule of Kibbud Av Veim, do parents have the right to tell their children to observe stringencies beyond required  Halacha?

Comment: Feed them, escort and dress emm

Comment: Do you mean that the parents demand for their children to observe Chumrahs that they themselves observe? If so, I'd say it would be more of a case of All Titosh Torat Imecha ([Pesachim 50b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.50b.11?lang=bi&lang2=en), [Chullin 93b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chullin.93b.3?lang=bi&lang2=en)), than of Kibbud Av Veim.